# How to find the parent ID in a return table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following table:

```
ID     ParentID
1         NULL
2          1
3          2
4          NULL
5          4
6          5
7          3
```

I want to find the first  ID of a specific child ID.
Example: ID=7 and the result is 1
ID=6     and the result is  4

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a bit of recursive CTE magic to solve this one.

Given the data in a table variable thusly:

```
declare @data table(id int, parentid int)
insert into @data
  select 1, null
  union select 2,1
  union select 3,2
  union select 4, null
  union select 5,4
  union select 6,5
  union select 7,3
```

The following should do the trick:

```
;with recursiveTable as
(
    select d.id, d.parentId, 0 as depth
    from @data d
    where d.id=6 -- Parameterize this
    union all

    select d.id, d.parentid, r.depth-1
    from @data d
    inner join recursiveTable r
    on d.id = r.parentId
)
select top 1 id 
from recursiveTable 
order by depth
```

Plugging `6` in as above returns `4`. Changing this to `7` returns `1` as requested.

Comment: Because that would be *far* too simple. ;) Talk about overthinking a solution, answer updated and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 CREATE TABLE childpar(ID int,ParentID int)
    INSERT INTO childpar 
    values(1,NULL),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 2),
    (4, NULL),
    (5, 4),
    (6, 5),
    (7, 3)


DECLARE @inpyID int
SET @inpyID=7

;WITH CTE1 as (
select * from childpar where id=@inpyID
union all
select c2.* from CTE1 c1 inner join childpar c2 on c1.ParentID = c2.ID
)

select top 1 id from CTE1 order by id asc
```

Comment: I dont see the point in the first CTE here, and also relies on the ids being lower for parents than children. Although this is the case for the OP I dont thiink you can assume it always is!

Comment: Still suffers from my second point above. You're relying on the order of id's

Comment: you are talking abt this "select top 1 id from CTE1 order by id asc
" statement?